# Excel Multi Conditional Formatting Questions

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, conditional-formatting, array

I need a formula that will look at the text in one cell and compare it to three other columns and highlight it a specified color.

Here's the example:

Data

- Cell A2 contains "This is the sample text in the cell"
- Cell B2 contains "sample"
- Cell C2 contains "text"
- Cell D2 contains "cell"

Desired Formula

1. If A2 contains B2 OR C2 OR D2, then highlight yellow
2. If A2 contains B2 AND C2, OR contains B2 AND D2, OR contains C2 AND D2, then highlight blue
3. If A2 contains B2 AND C2 AND D2, then highlight green

What I've Tried

- I've tried using `=SUM(COUNTIF(A2,"*"&B2&"*"))`. This works as desired for #1, but requires me to create separate formatting rules, one for B2, C2 and D2. So it isn't very elegant and I could not figure out the proper syntax to make it work for #2.
- For #3 I tried using `=SUM(COUNTIF(A2,"*"&B2:D2&"*"))` but this is returning false positives and displaying when only one cell meets the criteria.
- I've also tried `=SUMPRODUCT(--(A2=things))>0` (`things` = a named array) as detailed here: https://exceljet.net/formula/cell-equals-one-of-many-things 
  But this does not work as it requires me to create unique list names for every row.
- And I've also tried `=IF(OR(A2="sample",A2="text",A2="cell"),"True","False")` and then applying a conditional format for True outputs, but this does not work as it is dependent on hard-coded values.

The formula must be able to use dynamic values (the cell number A2, B2, C2 etc), it cannot be dependent on any hard values. I will need to use this formula for hundreds of rows, with different values plugged into each cell. So the formula must still work the same way for cells A3, B3, C3 and D3 without me needing to change anything. It needs to be a straight copy and paste into the column being evaluated, in this example it would be everything in column A.

I'm new here so I apologize if this has been answered elsewhere, I just can't find it. If so, please direct me to the answer!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions must demonstrate a reasonable amount of research & understanding of the problem being solved. Please edit to either a) clearly describe your problem and the research done so far to solve it or b) include attempted solutions plus why they didn't work. In either case, be sure your expected results are clearly presented.

Comment: I've added the formulas I've already tried. I've spent a good two hours trying stuff and Googling but nothing seems to work to my specs. I'd appreciate any help, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(-- ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B2:D2,$A$2)))
```

This is similar to your third attempt, but -

- you don't need to use a named range. You can just use `B2:D2`, which will work as you hope when you copy it down to the next row.
- you need to check whether the string contains the test values, rather than being equal to them.

`SEARCH` returns the starting point of one string inside another, `ISNUMBER` converts this to true or false depending on whether the string was found, and `--` converts the boolean value to a 0 or 1.  Passing a range of values to `SEARCH` means that the output is an array of 0s and 1s, rather than a single value.

Using `SUMPRODUCT` rather than `SUM` lets you add up these values without having to use Excel's array formula notation.  The end result is a number from 0 to 3, depending on how many of the comparisons succeeded, which you can test to drive the conditional formatting.

Note that if any of your comparison cells are blank, the comparison will succeed (as all strings contain the empty string).

(Based on the instructions at https://exceljet.net/formula/cell-contains-one-of-many-things)